# Sobotka's AgX in Godot 4?

Tags: godot, godot-4

Is it possible to use a custom OCIO called AgX in Godot 4? Has anyone ever tried something like this and succeeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [post regard ACES/OCIO on imported textures](https://forum.godotengine.org/t/aces-ocio-on-imported-textures/4719/2):

> Godot doesn’t support color management yet (or customizing tonemapping
> on import for HDR textures). Customizing tonemapping on import may be
> feasible with a custom script or import plugin.

That's the only hit I found [searching the Godot forums for OCIO](https://forum.godotengine.org/search?q=ocio) and searching the official documentation gave zero hits. Godot isn't listed on the game engine list at the [Open Color IO homepage](https://opencolorio.org). So my assumption is that it's still currently unsupported. Based on [this pull request](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/87260) it looks like adding AgX @Calinou options to the Godot Environment is under active development though.

As mentioned in the forum post, it might be may be feasible to do something via a script or plugin. I wasn't able to turn up an example, but that doesn't mean it can't be done or hasn't been tried.  You might be able to use the [color correction development demo](https://github.com/Calinou/godot-demo-projects/tree/add-color-correction-demo) to build something yourself, but based on some on the feedback in the pull request (linked earlier in the answer), it presently seems like the AgX results aren't meeting expectations yet.

Comment: Hope Godot adds it as an official option, because AgX is awesome.

Comment: @ThetaJones I was able to dig up a little bit more about AgX specifically & added the info as an edit. Looks like it's being worked on (which suprised me a little given the lack of proper support color management support), but the results for AgX need more work. I'm not sure how influential it is, but you could add some supporting reactions (thumbs up, etc) to the updates/posts to show your interest & moral support.

Comment: That's great to hear, the AgX looks really natural and I want it in my game.